# Getting list element giving compilation error: "Arrows are reserved for cases and anonymous functions. Maybe you want > or >= instead?"

Tags: elm

```elm
--define person type
type alias Person ={name: String, age: Int}

--created list of persons named people
people = [{name = "John", age = 41}, {name = "Nancy", age = 37}]
```

List item

```elm
names: List Person -> List String
names peeps = List.map(\peep -> peep.name) peeps
findPerson : String -> List Person -> Maybe Person

--using foldl to iterate list, here I am getting compile time error
findPerson name peeps = List.foldl(\peep memo -> case memo of Just _ -> 
Nothing -> if peep.name == name then Just peep else Nothing ) Nothing peeps

main = text <| toString <| findPerson "John" people
```

Comment: When you were asking your question, there was a big orange **How to Format** box to the right of the text area with useful information in it. There was also an entire toolbar of formatting aids. And a **[?]** button giving formatting help. *And* a preview area located between the text area and the Post Your Question button (so that you'd have to scroll past it to find the button, to encourage you to look at it) showing what your post would look like when posted. Making your post clear, and demonstrating that you took the time to do so, improves your chances of getting good answers.

Comment: (I'd help you out this time formatting it, but I don't know elm.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Elm is whitespace-sensitive. The lines you flagged have invalid Elm code.

Your case statements should be in the form of:

```elm
case something of
    Just val -> "we have a valid value: " ++ val
    Nothing -> "we have nothing"
```

Furthermore, a `foldl` is probably not what you want for finding something in a list. You could get by with this implementation, which filters a list and takes the first element, if it exists.

```elm
findPerson : String -> List Person -> Maybe Person
findPerson name peeps =
    List.filter (\peep -> peep.name == name) peeps
        |> List.head
```

Comment: Thanks Chad, your answer helped.

Comment: @Ish There is a small tick to click on, under the up and down-vote arrows.